# Store results in a separate library for later loading

Tags: c++

If I have some set of results which can be calculated at compile-time, and I want to use them elsewhere in a program, can I place them in a (shared?) library for later linking? Will this be slower?

For example, I can calculate factorials at compile time using

```
template<size_t N>
struct Factorial {
    constexpr static size_t value = Factorial<N-1>::value * N;
};

template<>
struct Factorial<0> {
    constexpr static size_t value = 1;
};

// Possibly an instantiation for a max value?
// template class Factorial<50>;
```

Then to use this in code, I just write `Factorial<32>::value`, or similar.

If I assume that my real values take somewhat longer to compute, then I might want to ensure that they aren't recomputed on each build / on any build that considers the old build to be invalid.

Consequently, I move the calculating code into a separate project, which I compile as a shared library.

Now, to use it, I link my main program to the library, and `#include` the header.

However, the library file is rather small (and seemingly independent of the value passed to create the template), and so I wonder if in fact, the library is only holding the methods to create a `Factorial` struct, and not the precomputed data.

How can I calculate a series of values and then use them in a separate program?

Solutions which provide compile-time value injection would be preferred - I note that loading a shared library does not fall into this category *(I think)*

Comment: I think you need a better example. The time it takes to calculate any factorial that can fit into a size_t can be measured in microseconds, at compile time *or* run time. You are prematurely optimizing something that is trivial. What are you really trying to optimize?

Comment: Stencil calculation for N-wide stencils for Finite Difference fluid mechanics - The matrix inversion (perhaps by LUT) of an NxN matrix and finding the solution vector (Nx1) that solves Ax=B where `B=std::array<type, N>; B.fill(T(0); B[k]=1;` for one value of `0<k<N`; Types also likely to include `boost::rational`, or similar. [Reference notes](http://people.ucalgary.ca/~dfeder/535/FDnotes.pdf) suggest one set of calculations could take 'on the order of an hour on a basic personal computer' - the library or data store I'm attempting to create would likely be smaller than this but hold two sets

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is the actual "code" that does the calculation is still in the header. Putting it into a shared library didn't really do anything; the compiler is still recomputing the factorials for your main program. (So, your intuition is correct.)

A better approach is to write another program to spit out the values as a the source code for a C++ constant array, then copy and paste them into your code. This will probably take about 5 lines of Python, and your C++ code will compile and run quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the variables as part of your build process (through a seperated application which you compile and invoke as part of your build process) and store the result in a generated source file.
With CMake, (`configure_file`) Makefiles or NMake for example it should be very easy.

You could use the generated source file to generate a shared library as you suggested or you could link/ include the generated sources into your application directly.

An advantage of this approach is that you are not limited to compile time calculation anymore,
you could also use runtime calculation which will be faster since it can be optimized.